# What debugging tool to test image load on phone?

Tags: angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

i am currently coding a website loading a lot of images.

I use Bootstrap for responsiveness, Angular and javascript.

As you can see here : www.carteldelart.com/article/messager, the other articles are referenced with a thumbnail image i load using a directive that draw an image with the following code :

```
app.directive("messager", function(){
    return function(scope, element){
        angular.element(document).ready(function(){
            // on récupère l'élément
            var myUrl = "myUrl";
            var thumbnail_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            thumbnail_canvas.width = 125;
            thumbnail_canvas.height = 125;

            var imageTmp = new Image();
            imageTmp.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

            imageTmp.onload = function(){
                thumbnail_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageTmp, 6, 0, 794, 794, 0, 0, 125, 125);
                document.getElementById("messager").style.backgroundImage = "url("+thumbnail_canvas.toDataURL()+")";
            }
            imageTmp.src = myUrl;
        });
    }
});
```

The page and images loads well, the chrome testing tools seems things are going well on phones as well.

BUT, when i load the page on an actual phone, the size of the loaded image is not the good one for some of the images!

[image]

I'd like to debbug on my phone. Do you know any tool for this?

Have you experienced that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Two aspects in the question :

1. Debug tool for iOS.
2. Correctly display images on iOS devices.

**1. Debug tool**

Open iOS simulator from xcode. On safari, load the webpage to be tested.
From safari, development menu, click on iOS simulator > the page you just loaded.
From iOS simulator, reload the webpage.
Go back to safari to get logs after your webpage runned.

**2. Correctly display images on iOS devices.**

Some reduced images does not vertically scale right as presented on the question. It is due to a limitation from safari impacting device with devicePixelRatio > 1.

The solution is to detect the "vertical squash" parameters inside the image to redraw it with different vertical squash parameters.

The solution to the problem is to embed stomita ios-image-megapixel library when loading image : https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel